# How can I unpack a list of list in python of string type

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, unpack

I have gone through couple of related questions but those were cases where the list of list is of integer or single character . The below query what I am posting is bit different .

```
audit_cols=['foundation_program_nam','foundation_ins_dt']
schema_list=["customer id","employee id","phoneno"]

target_schema=['order_key',schema_list,'order_year',audit_cols]
print(target_schema)
```

## If I run this , the output it prints

```
['order_key', ['customer id', 'employee id', 'phoneno'], 'order_year', ['foundation_program_nam', 'foundation_ins_dt']]
```

## But what I am looking for , is this

```
['order_key', 'customer id', 'employee id', 'phoneno', 'order_year', 'foundation_program_nam', 'foundation_ins_dt']
```

Comment: try this, ```target_schema=['order_key',*schema_list,'order_year',*audit_cols]```

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you getting stuck?  As a starter, look at the `itertools.chain` function.

Comment: I tried that but that splits the string to single character

Comment: This question is not a duplicate to the provided answer in the sense that the provided answer solves the problem algorithmically, while OP is dealing with literal values. For this problem, there exists a more straightforward solution, namely list unpacking, as mentioned

Comment: @Sushanth It worked thanks .